# Is NashornScriptEngine thread-safe?

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

Anyone can clarify whether NashornScriptEngine is thread-safe or not? 
If it is not thread-safe, how to handle multiple scripts?

Comment: have you read https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/nashorn_multi_threading_and_mt ?

Comment: NOT thread-safe. DO NOT FOLLOW THE ANSWER!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The engine itself is thread-safe **but the answer isn't a simple yes/no so keep on reading.**

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159424/466771) from someone with excellent credentials on this topic.

I'm not going to copy/paste the entire answer, but it starts off with this:

> You can share a ScriptEngine and CompiledScript objects across
>   threads. They are threadsafe. Actually, you should share them, as a
>   single engine instance is a holder for a class cache and for
>   JavaScript objects' hidden classes, so by having only one you cut down
>   on repeated compilation.
>
> What you can't share is Bindings objects ...

Make sure to read the rest of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159424/466771)!