# Nashorn in thread safe manner

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, nashorn, scriptengine

Below I have shared my code in which I am trying to use thread safe Nashorn  as scripting engine to evaluate simple mathematical formula. Formula will be like "a*b/2" where a & b will be picked up from map object.

```
public class EvaluateFormulas {

@Autowired
NashornThreadPool pool;

private ScriptEngineManager factory;
private ScriptEngine engine;
private ScriptContext context;

@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    context = engine.getContext();
}

public void evaluate() {
    pool.getThreadPoolExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Double result;
            Bindings bind = engine.createBindings();
            bind.putAll(map);
            context.setBindings(bind, ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);
            try {
                result = (Double) engine.eval(formula);
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}   
}
```

I need to know whether this approach will help making Nashorn thread safe for this use case. I read in Attila`s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140103/should-i-use-a-separate-scriptengine-and-compiledscript-instances-per-each-threa/30159424#30159424) that we can share script engine objects between threads since they are thread safe.

For bindings and eval, since we are creating new thread for each execution of ***evaluate*** and each thread has its own object reference for bindings object. So in its entirety, will this implementation be thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will be threadsafe, since you're changing the bindings while another thread could potentially be executing code. You actually don't need to be doing this; you can just create a brand-new context and then evaluate the script in that context. I would do something like this:

```
public void evaluate() {
    pool.getThreadPoolExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Double result;

            ScriptContext myContext = new SimpleScriptContext();
            Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
            bindings.putAll(map);
            myContext.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

            try {
                result = (Double) engine.eval(formula, myContext);
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now each script gets evaluated in its own context.

Comment: I am using separate Binding object for each execution like `SimpleBindings simpleBindings = new SimpleBindings();` and then `engine.eval(script, simpleBindings);` . I completely skipped using context. Is that thread safe?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I'm guessing not because it will use the same context.