# Attempting to make Nashorn thread safe

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, nashorn

I've recently been working with the Play! framework and Nashorn in an attempt to render a Redux application. Initially, I had implemented multiple Nashorn engines in a ThreadPoolExecutor and used futures when running `engine.eval()`. The performance was terrible, I'm assuming due to the high I/O and the blocking future I was using.

After becoming more familiar with Play! and their async/promise pattern, I attempted to start over with just a single `ScriptEngine`; per https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159424/5956783, the script engine itself is thread safe, however bindings are not. Here is the class in its entirety:

```
package services;

import akka.actor.ActorSystem;

import play.libs.F;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext;

import java.io.FileReader;


import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.script.*;

@Singleton
public class NashornEngine extends JSEngineAbstract {

    private NashornThread engine;
    private final ActorSystem actorSystem;


    protected class NashornThread {
        private ScriptEngine engine;
        private final ExecutionContext executionContext = actorSystem.dispatchers().lookup("js-engine-executor");
        private CompiledScript compiledScript;


        public NashornThread() {
            try {
                String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                this.engine = new ScriptEngineManager(null).getEngineByName("nashorn");
                this.compiledScript = ((Compilable) this.engine).compile(new FileReader(dir + "/public/javascripts/bundle.js"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public ScriptEngine getEngine() {
            return engine;
        }

        public F.Promise<String> getContent(String path, String globalCode) {
            return F.Promise.promise(() -> this.executeMethod(path, globalCode), this.executionContext);
        }

        private String executeMethod(String path, String json) throws ScriptException {
            Bindings newBinding = engine.createBindings();
            try {
                this.compiledScript.eval(newBinding);
                getEngine().setBindings(newBinding, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
                getEngine().eval("var global = this;");
                getEngine().eval("var console = {log: print, error: print, warn: print};");
                String result = getEngine().eval("App.renderApp('" + path + "', " + json + ")").toString();

                return result;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }


    @Inject
    public NashornEngine(ActorSystem actorSystem) {
        this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
        this.engine = new NashornThread();
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<String> getContent(String path, String globalCode) {
        try {
            F.Promise<String> result = engine.getContent(path, globalCode);

            return result.map((String r) -> r);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My JavaScript application exports an `App` object with the method `renderApp(path, state)` visible. This actually *does* work, but only 16 times (yes, always 16). Starting with iteration 17, I get the following exception and accompanying stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeRegExpExecResult cannot be cast to jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray.getContinuousArrayDataCCE(NativeArray.java:1900)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray.popObject(NativeArray.java:937)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:660)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:228)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23589$782286AA$\^eval\_.L:22918$L:22920$matchPattern(<eval>:23049)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23588$816752AAAAAA$\^eval\_.L:24077$L:24079$matchRouteDeep(<eval>:24168)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23587$820262DAA$\^eval\_.L:24077$L:24079$matchRoutes$L:24252$L:24253(<eval>:24254)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23586$809060$\^eval\_.L:23848$loopAsync$next(<eval>:23869)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23584$808906AAA$\^eval\_.L:23848$loopAsync(<eval>:23875)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23583$820189$\^eval\_.L:24077$L:24079$matchRoutes$L:24252(<eval>:24253)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23582$819862AAA$\^eval\_.L:24077$L:24079$matchRoutes(<eval>:24252)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23580$789440AA$\^eval\_.L:23151$L:23153$useRoutes$L:23209$match(<eval>:23239)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23518$847004AA$\^eval\_.L:25026$L:25028$match(<eval>:25084)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23468$3872AA$\^eval\_.L:53$renderApp(<eval>:147)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$23467$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:640)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:228)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:446)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:403)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at services.NashornEngine$NashornThread.executeMethod(NashornEngine.java:62)
    at services.NashornEngine$NashornThread.lambda$getContent$0(NashornEngine.java:48)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$promise$2.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:36)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I am under the impression that creating a new binding with the compiled script would be treated as net-new to the engine, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What, if anything, am I doing wrong here?

I have attempted to use an `Invocable` as well to invoke the method on the `App` object, but that doesn't make any difference.

**EDIT**
I'm on an 8 core machine with hyper-threading, so that may explain the 16 successful attempts before the failed 17th attempt. Also, I've updated the `executeMethod` method to below:

```
private String executeMethod(String path, String json) throws ScriptException {
            Bindings newBinding = engine.createBindings();
            try {
                this.compiledScript.eval(newBinding);
                getEngine().eval("var global = this;", newBinding);
                getEngine().eval("var console = {log: print, error: print, warn: print};", newBinding);
                Object app = getEngine().eval("App", newBinding);
                Invocable invEngine = (Invocable) getEngine();
                String result = invEngine.invokeMethod(app, "renderApp", path, json).toString();
//              String result = getEngine().eval("App.renderApp('" + path + "', " + json + ")", newBinding).toString();

                return result;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you hit a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145550) in Nashorn. The good news is that it was fixed already, and the fix is available in [current early access releases](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

Answer (score 2):

Updating to the latest version of Nashorn, or Java 1.8u76 fixes the issue.