# Better way to load custom DSL config from Java application

Tags: java, dsl, jsr223

For a Java application, is there a better way to support configuration files based on a custom DSL (such as relying on Groovy or Kotlin) than using JSR223 `ScriptEngine`'s `eval` or `compile` methods?

Loading script's content as `String` and then using it in a code like that is working but maybe there are better and more efficient ways of doing it.

```
String type = "groovy"; // or "kts"
String script = "...";  // code of DSL script
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByExtension(type);
Compilable compiler = (Compilable) engine;
CompiledScript code = compiler.compile(script);
Object result = code.eval();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually as [JMeter](https://apache.googlesource.com/jmeter/+/v2_11/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/JSR223TestElement.java), you should save your compiled script in cache and use it:

> ```
> CompiledScript compiledScript = compiledScriptsCache.get(newCacheKey);
> ```

Same for [ScriptEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140103/should-i-use-a-separate-scriptengine-and-compiledscript-instances-per-each-threa)

> You can share a ScriptEngine and CompiledScript objects across threads. They are threadsafe. Actually, you should share them, as a single engine instance is a holder for a class cache and for JavaScript objects' hidden classes, so by having only one you cut down on repeated compilation.